# _beginthread In Parent Constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance

Given the situation:

```
class A {};
class B : A;

B b;
```

If the default constructor for `class A` creates a thread using `_beginthread`, is it possible for that thread to have started executing before the constructor for `class B` has finished instantiating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread will certainly have been created since the constructor of `A` is completely executed before the constructor of `B` begins execution.  That thread may or may not have started, though:  that would depend on how the threads are scheduled and what you do in the constructor after you create the thread.  It certainly *may* have started.

Comment: Following that through then, if the thread 'can' start during A(), I assume that virtual functions in B must be registered before A() is called?

Comment: @Nicholas: During `A()`, the dynamic type of the object is `A`, not `B`. You won't be able to call any virtual functions on the object which calls `_beginthread` in it's constructor in the new thread.

Comment: @Nicholas:  Basically, what @DeadMG said.  If you have a virtual function declared in `A`, then that function in `A` will be called, not an overrider in `B`.

Comment: So just to clarify, if the thread did start during A() and calls a virtual function v(), then A::v() is called. But if the thread starts after B() has finished, then B::v() is called. Or is it because the thread is started at all inside the constructor of A() that A::v() is only ever called irrelevant of when the thread actually starts?

Comment: @Nicholas:  If virtual member functions are called from the other thread before `B()` begins execution, then the member functions in `A` will be used.  If the member functions are called from the other thread after `B()` begins execution, then the member functions in `B` will be used.  Note that calling virtual member functions during construction and destruction is generally a bad idea because it's often confusing to remember which function will actually be called.    Calling virtual functions from a different thread started during construction is doubly bad.

Comment: @Nicholas: This is triply unsafe because you may end up calling a pure virtual function too which has no implementation.